# if cn is the entry why can't i use while cn

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

1. I'm supposed to create a GUI program that will double every second
   digit starting from right to left.
2. If the result of a doubled number is greater than 10 then I add the
   two digits (example: `9x2=18`, `1+8=9`.) then I'm supposed to add
   every number in the odd places.
3. Then add the two sums together and if it is divisible by 10 it is
   valid. But I'm stuck at trying to get the digits out of the entry.
4. I only get errors in everything I try. cn is the text variable for
   the entry

**My code:**

```
from tkinter import*
card.Tk()
card.geometry("300x300+500+100")
card.title('Credit Card Validator')
cn=StringVar()
digit_list=[]
even=[]
odd=[]
card['backgroun']='#0AF3C1'
Label(card,bg='#0AF3C1',text='Card Number').place(x=30, y=60)
Entry(card,width=20,bg='#0AF3C1',textvariable=cn).place(x=120, y=60)
def digits():
ans=0
sum=0
while cn():
    ans=c_n%10
    cn=c_n//10
    digit_list.append(ans)
for index in range(0,len(digit_list)):
    if index%2==0:
        even.append(digit_list[index])
    else:
        odd.append(digit_list[index])
print(digit_list)
Button(card,text='Done',command=digits).place(x=120, y=200)
card.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation? Also `cn` is a `StringVar` not a `tkinter.Entry`. Also what are you trying to do with `cn()` in `while cn()`? I don't think `StringVar` objects are callable

Comment: The method for getting a value out of a `StringVar` and an `Entry` are well documented, without countless examples on the internet. Have you read any documentation or done any research?